# Get elasticsearch template in json format using java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have tried using the admin API and was able to get mappings as `json` format using something like below

```
String mappings = client.admin  
                        .indices  
                        .getTemplates (new GetIndexTemplatesRequest ("template_name"))  
                        .actionGet ()  
                        .getIndexTemplates.get (0)  
                        .getMappings  
                        .get ("mapping_name")  
                        .toString ();
```

but I dont have any method to extract the similar for the complete template or settings. 
I could see a method in settings to convert to XDocumentBuilder, but I am mot sure how to convert that setting to `json`

How can I extract the complete template or at least settings in `json` format??